# creating a consumer by cloning the provider in openldap, anything wrong with that?

Tags: openldap, centos7, master-slave

I have setup an ldap server on centos 7 as a provider and created a consumer by simply cloning the provider and adding syncrepl.ldif to it and seems to work just fine. In all the documentations and examples that I am reading, no one mentions doing a clone they and basically rebuild the same server and add a syncrepl.ldif to it. Is there a reason for that? Is there a consequence to what I have done?

Answer (score 0):

If you start up an empty consumer it pulls the whole directory from the provider, so cloning the data is mostly unnecessary except in cases where the directory contents are so big that the transfer would be undesirable due to the size of the transfer and/or the load it would place on the producer.